# Hover function implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to user a Hover on Contact Title text. I would like that Displayed content follows the cursor too.
I made a jsfiddle with my hover but I don't know why isn't working...

### HTML

```
<div class="toggleSwitch_j">
    <a href="#"> Contact Title </a>
    <div class="SignatureBox">Text Displayed</div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.SignatureBox {
    display: none; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #F9F7F7;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.SignatureBox').hide();
    $('.toggleSwitch_j').hover(function () {
        $(this).children('.SignatureBox').show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).children('.SignatureBox').hide();
    });
});
```

### DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/u3pW8/2/

Comment: Because you need to include JQuery in the left panel : http://jsfiddle.net/u3pW8/3/

Comment: OK thx for help ! Last question, How can I implement that Text Displayed follows the cursor

Comment: Please include jQuery in your code :

http://jsfiddle.net/manishkumarshr/u3pW8/8/

Comment: @user2706463 For you second query Text Displayed follows the cursor. I have set up a fiddle. see below answer of mine

Comment: @Akki619 I saw your example but Text Displayed is not in th html code

Comment: @user2706463 see my updated fiddle and code in my answer. I have displayed your text from Html page only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pageX and pageY with .offset() function

```
$(this).children('.SignatureBox').show().offset({left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u3pW8/27/)

whole code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('.SignatureBox').hide();
        $('.toggleSwitch_j').hover(function (e) {

            $(this).children('.SignatureBox').show().offset({left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY});
        }, function () {
            $(this).children('.SignatureBox').hide();
        });

 });
```

Comment: Thx this is eaxctly what I was looking for !! Last question how Can I block the case when the Text Displayed is on same line of Contact Title.

http://postimg.org/image/fwst2u30h/

Comment: @user2706463 If this is exactly the answer, please click on the tick to show that the answer is approved. Follow up questions usually get a better response as separate questions rather than hidden away in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need javascript for this but problem in your example is that you haven't loaded jQuery. You can do that from the top left navigation in JSFiddle.

Here is an example in JSFiddle using only CSS: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MartinTale/u3pW8/31/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span>Visible Content (Hover Me)</span>
    <span class="hidden-content">Hidden Content (Visible when hovered)</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.hidden-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.wrapper:hover .hidden-content {
    display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".wrapper").hover(function (e) {
        var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        $(".hidden-content").css("left", relX);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thx for help, but I would like the hidden Content displayed at the same  X coordonate when cursor is on the Hover Me

Comment: Added some javascript to account for moving the hidden content on X coordinate. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for implementation , last thing I would like that if Text Displayed at X he stays at this position, no  Slide-in

Comment: Now you can see both sliding and static X position for hidden content in JSFiddle example.

Comment: @user2706463 you can then approve this answer as a correct one ;) Good luck with your project.

Comment: thx !! Just last question, I tried to add a setimeout function to display the text but not working ...

Comment: @user2706463 You should make that as a seperate question as it is now completely unrelated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way just using CSS

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
LINK
<p class="text">text</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper .text {
position:relative;
bottom:10px;
left:0px;
visibility:hidden;
}

#wrapper:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: Thx for help, but I would like the hidden Content displayed at the same X coordonate when cursor is on the Hover Me

I tried your code and same problem. Text loaded same position everytime.

Comment: Thx !! But Indeed I would like this for example when cursor is on C of Contact

http://postimg.org/image/wwtbsjmip

when he is on T of Title


http://postimg.org/image/tehbw5lmp

Answer (score 0):

You should load jQuery to use `jQuery hover` function.
Select jQuery 1.x library in the left framework panel.

http://jsfiddle.net/eg5bV/1/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** : `(http://jsfiddle.net/u3pW8/23/)`

Also load jquery on left side bar.I have made some change in script.

Comment: Thx !! But Indeed I would like this for example when cursor is on C of Contact

http://postimg.org/image/wwtbsjmip

when he is on T of Title


http://postimg.org/image/tehbw5lmp

Answer (score 0):

I have set up a jsfilddle for your second query.

Please see [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Akki619/DjwM4/2/) fiddle to **Text Displayed follows the cursor**

**JS:**

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
$('.SignatureBox').hide();
        $('.toggleSwitch_j').hover(function () {
            $(this).children('.SignatureBox').show();

    //attach the mousemove event
    $(window).bind('mousemove mouseover', function(evt) {

         $(".SignatureBox").offset({left:evt.pageX, top: evt.pageY});
    });
        }, function () {
            $(this).children('.SignatureBox').hide();
        });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in full css3 :

```
.toggleSwitch_j{
    pointer: cursor;
}

.toggleSwitch_j:hover > .SignatureBox {
    display: block; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #F9F7F7;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}

.SignatureBox {
    display: none;
}
```

the > indicator signify the hover on the first element do result on the second (if the second is inside the first).